# Cross domain JQuery load() does not work for specific site

Tags: jquery, load, cross-domain

I am using Jquery to load a page's html and then select specific parts of it. But for some reason this does not work on the site I want to use it for (#1). Using firebug I can see that it does not receive an answer containing the html of the page. Can anyone explain why it does not work?

```
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#1').load("http://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:310574-2011:TEXT:EN:HTML p");
        $('#2').load("http://www.google.com a");

    }
);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="1"></p>
  <p id="2"></p>
</body>
```

The answer on the request showing no result:

```
jsonp1319995924645({"query":{"count":"0","created":"2011-10-30T17:32:10Z","lang":"en-US"},"results":[]});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Use any jQuery AJAX function and set `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: I have read that yes, but this jquery.xdomainajax.js makes it possible to do this. It does work for www.google.com (or any random site i tried), but not for the ted.europa.eu, and I don't understand why not.

Comment: Use any jQuery AJAX function and set dataType: "jsonp"